# HAProxy + mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache, haproxy, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have currently 3 web server configuration with HAProxy dividing the traffic to one of each web server. Each server is running apache2 with mod_pagespeed. The HAProxy takes care of the SSL termination as the web servers are in local network.

HAProxy sets the X-Forwareded-Proto header to each request and I have enabled "ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on" in each pagespeed configuration.

Apache services are running in custom port 8012 and now I am getting an error to javascript console from pagespeed when going to the site:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.example.com:8012/_,Mjo.NZsywmsdso.js.pagespeed.jm.OLNkjPSHpv.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Any idea what could still be wrong? Here is the pagespeed HTTPS configuration:

```
ModPagespeedFetchFromModSpdy on
ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable
ModPagespeedSslCertDirectory /etc/ssl/certs
ModPagespeedSslCertFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://www.example.com" "https://www.example.com"
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pagespeed seems to add the javascript file <script pagespeed_no_defer="" src="http://www.example.com:8012/_.pagespeed.jo.xjKDFYrnea.js"></script> in the HTML. Any idea if I can change that address with some configuration?

Comment: Seems the problem disappeared when removing filter ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_mobile_images,insert_image_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I am going to answer how I fix it on my own setup.

The issue comes if you are using pagespeed on each server vs somehow running it on haproxy itself for caching. Since pagespeed saves a copy of any modified file with a modification on filename, then it also changes the source of the HTML to match that new filename it stored, which should work fine. But the issue is that is pagespeed on web server 1 is modifying the HTML to match background compressing of the files(images, js, css, etc) then when it gets to the users computer and their browser requests such files it wont find it if you are round-robin it between servers because that file will be only on web server 1 and not on the others, the way around it is to use a shared folder for the pagespeed so when one compresses a file into that folder, the other web servers will see it through their pagespeed.